# Sorting dataview from datatable with hidden columns in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in an ASP.NET Web Forms app and I needed to add a way to sort the rows based on 2 columns. I found a way to do that using DataView.

So from my original Gridview I am creating a DataTable and then I do:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = "Column_1, Column_2";
gridView.DataSource = dv;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Now I can sort the DataView and after that I can add the DataView to the Gridview as a DataSource. This works great, except that my original GridView has some columns that are set to visible=false.
After I do this sorting, the data from the columns that are hidden gets deleted.

Does this happen when I create the DataView from the DataTable or when I do the sort? What could I do to keep the values from the hidden columns?

Comment: I managed to solve this by making the GridView columns visible first and then doing all the other stuff needed for the sort and at the end I put the GridView columns back to not visible. This works but I was more curious about why is this happening. I couldn't find any related info online. Perhaps someone with more experience could shed some light. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Before sorting you have to set columns `visible=false` and after sorting set `visible=true` will work better below code for sorting:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = "Column_1, Column_2";
gridView.DataSource = dv;
gridView.DataBind();
```

This works as you have not checked `IsPostBack` in `Page_Load`.